# Prevent compiling a package from amongst several packages in a netbeans project

Tags: java, netbeans

How to prevent compiling a package from amongst several packages in a netbeans based web app project?

Actually there are certain classes within *that package* that are uncompilable & they actually are responsible for not any of the other packages in project, making it to `../target/classes/` folder. While building the project I saw that the packages were compiled however there are no class files in the `../target/classes/` folder. However if I remove the uncompilable package, all the other packages successfully make it to `../target/classes/` folder.

Comment: Why not making it right, and fixing the code that doesn't compile? Or remove it completely if it doesn't serve any purpose?

Answer (score 5):

This is covered in the [NetBeans FAQ](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeansUserFAQ#Compiling_and_Building_Projects) in the question: "[Can I exclude some classes or packages from compilation](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqExcludes)"

- Goto Project Properties
- Select the "Sources" node in the left hand tree
- Click on Include/Excludes in the lower left corner
- Specify which files to exclude in the lower input field.

Answer (score 0):

I dont about netbeans.. but in eclipse you an add an exclusion filter on the src directory. I am pretty sure you could do the same in netbeans too. And I think netbeans creates ant build file for the project, you could try modifying that file.